# Choropleth map based on counties using map_data in R

Tags: r, choropleth

I am trying to create a choropleth map of Alabama counties based on the election results of a special election. The map should be returning with a 10 class RdBl palette where the counties that have Jones in the Winner column are 5 shades of blue with the highest interval being the darkest, and those with Moore in the Winner column are 5 shades of red with the highest interval being the darkest. Here is the code I currently have which isn't returning a map yet:

```
# load libraries
library(RColorBrewer)
library(maps)

# Define the breaks and colors
breaks <- c(45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 83, 86, 90)
blue_colors <- brewer.pal(5, "Blues")
red_colors <- brewer.pal(5, "Reds")

map_data <- map_data("county", region = "alabama")
map_data <- map_data %>% rename(County = subregion)
etable$County <- tolower(etable$County)
names(etable)

common_col <- "County"
etable_with_longlat <- merge(etable, map_data[, c(common_col, "long", "lat")], by = common_col, all.x = TRUE)

vote_data <- etable_with_longlat[, c("County", "JonesPct", "MoorePct", "long", "lat")]

# Create a new column indicating the candidate who won the county
vote_data$Winner <- ifelse(is.na(vote_data$JonesPct), "Moore",
                           ifelse(is.na(vote_data$MoorePct), "Jones",
                                  ifelse(vote_data$JonesPct >= vote_data$MoorePct, "Jones", "Moore")))

vote_data$VotePct <- ifelse(is.na(vote_data$JonesPct),
                            paste0(vote_data$MoorePct),
                            ifelse(is.na(vote_data$MoorePct),
                                   paste0(vote_data$JonesPct),
                                   paste0(vote_data$JonesPct, vote_data$MoorePct)))

# Convert VotePct to a numeric format
vote_data$VotePct <- as.numeric(vote_data$VotePct)

# Create separate data frames for the "Jones" and "Moore" winners
jones_data <- subset(vote_data, Winner == "Jones")[, c(1, 4, 5, 6, 7)]
moore_data <- subset(vote_data, Winner == "Moore")[, c(1, 4, 5, 6, 7)]

vote_data <- rbind(jones_data, moore_data)
names(vote_data)
str(vote_data)
# Create the plot with separate color scales for "Jones" and "Moore" winners
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = vote_data, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = County, fill = cut(VotePct, breaks = breaks)), color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(name = "Vote Percentage", colors = c(blue_colors, red_colors), breaks = breaks, na.value = "white") +
  theme_void()
```

This particular version is returning the error: `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`

The structure of the data is as follows:

```
> str(vote_data)
'data.frame':   2959 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ County : chr  "barbour" "barbour" "barbour" "barbour" ...
 $ long   : num  -85.4 -85.7 -85.2 -85.1 -85.1 ...
 $ lat    : num  31.6 31.7 31.8 31.8 31.9 ...
 $ Winner : chr  "Jones" "Jones" "Jones" "Jones" ...
 $ VotePct: num  57.3 57.3 57.3 57.3 57.3 ...
```

I'm attaching the head and tail dput of the vote_data for clarity on what I'm working with, the data was too long to attach the whole thing:

```
> dput(head(vote_data))
structure(list(County = c("barbour", "barbour", "barbour", "barbour", 
"barbour", "barbour"), long = c(-85.4280090332031, -85.6972961425781, 
-85.1529846191406, -85.1358032226562, -85.1071472167969, -85.2217483520508
), lat = c(31.6158123016357, 31.7475910186768, 31.7876968383789, 
31.7876968383789, 31.9366664886475, 31.7132129669189), Winner = c("Jones", 
"Jones", "Jones", "Jones", "Jones", "Jones"), VotePct = c(57.3208722741433, 
57.3208722741433, 57.3208722741433, 57.3208722741433, 57.3208722741433, 
57.3208722741433)), row.names = 168:173, class = "data.frame")

> dput(tail(vote_data))
structure(list(County = c("winston", "winston", "winston", "winston", 
"winston", "winston"), long = c(-87.6281661987305, -87.6281661987305, 
-87.525032043457, -87.6281661987305, -87.1125030517578, -87.1125030517578
), lat = c(34.3087120056152, 34.3087120056152, 34.3029823303223, 
34.0107727050781, 34.2972526550293, 33.9993171691895), Winner = c("Moore", 
"Moore", "Moore", "Moore", "Moore", "Moore"), VotePct = c(82.7147401908802, 
82.7147401908802, 82.7147401908802, 82.7147401908802, 82.7147401908802, 
82.7147401908802)), row.names = 2954:2959, class = "data.frame")
```

here is the dput for etable:

```
> dput(etable)
structure(list(County = c("Jefferson", "Madison", "Mobile", "Montgomery", 
"Shelby", "Baldwin", "Tuscaloosa", "Lee", "Morgan", "Etowah", 
"Calhoun", "Limestone", "Houston", "Lauderdale", "St. Clair", 
"Elmore", "Cullman", "Talladega", "Marshall", "Walker", "Colbert", 
"Autauga", "Blount", "Dallas", "DeKalb", "Coffee", "Tallapoosa", 
"Dale", "Jackson", "Russell", "Chilton", "Covington", "Escambia", 
"Lawrence", "Clarke", "Pike", "Chambers", "Marengo", "Geneva", 
"Marion", "Monroe", "Macon", "Barbour", "Pickens", "Franklin", 
"Butler", "Winston", "Cherokee", "Hale", "Bibb", "Washington", 
"Henry", "Randolph", "Lowndes", "Fayette", "Sumter", "Wilcox", 
"Choctaw", "Conecuh", "Perry", "Greene", "Crenshaw", "Lamar", 
"Clay", "Bullock", "Coosa", "Cleburne"), Jones = c(149522, 65664, 
62253, 48186, 27251, 22131, 30858, 19810, 10901, 10518, 11705, 
9606, 9107, 9908, 6203, 7711, 4156, 9967, 5134, 4317, 6865, 5606, 
2405, 10492, 3559, 3715, 4590, 3842, 3328, 6761, 2298, 2102, 
3640, 3028, 4346, 3989, 4247, 4495, 1289, 1311, 3244, 5780, 3680, 
3057, 1770, 2914, 911, 1525, 3894, 1567, 1799, 1896, 1692, 3779, 
1142, 3527, 3344, 2273, 2259, 3138, 3340, 1320, 779, 985, 2712, 
1414, 594), Moore = c(66309, 46313, 46725, 17705, 36424, 38445, 
22064, 14017, 19187, 15693, 14567, 14298, 14796, 12775, 15876, 
14411, 16602, 9698, 13828, 11909, 7762, 8752, 11621, 3485, 10097, 
8052, 7171, 6988, 7316, 3622, 7555, 6825, 4985, 5314, 3984, 4154, 
3308, 2804, 5431, 5268, 3276, 758, 2699, 2961, 4214, 2756, 4680, 
3996, 1691, 3599, 3320, 3014, 3229, 988, 3491, 814, 999, 1949, 
1815, 821, 462, 2347, 2847, 2586, 656, 1867, 2465), WriteIns = c(3710, 
3446, 1539, 743, 1718, 1699, 1007, 672, 668, 617, 399, 515, 285, 
382, 459, 338, 324, 223, 449, 259, 171, 253, 180, 60, 234, 202, 
148, 136, 154, 55, 132, 88, 87, 61, 43, 97, 75, 62, 93, 68, 40, 
20, 41, 46, 48, 41, 67, 110, 32, 66, 48, 38, 23, 13, 50, 18, 
16, 17, 18, 11, 9, 56, 29, 44, 7, 30, 30), Rpt = c("100%", "100%", 
"100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", 
"100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", 
"100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", 
"100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", 
"100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", 
"100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", 
"100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", 
"100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", 
"100%"), Total = c(219541, 115423, 110517, 66634, 65393, 62275, 
53929, 34499, 30756, 26828, 26671, 24419, 24188, 23065, 22538, 
22460, 21082, 19888, 19411, 16485, 14798, 14611, 14206, 14037, 
13890, 11969, 11909, 10966, 10798, 10438, 9985, 9015, 8712, 8403, 
8373, 8240, 7630, 7361, 6813, 6647, 6560, 6558, 6420, 6064, 6032, 
5711, 5658, 5631, 5617, 5232, 5167, 4948, 4944, 4780, 4683, 4359, 
4359, 4239, 4092, 3970, 3811, 3723, 3655, 3615, 3375, 3311, 3089
), JonesPct = c(68.1066406730406, 56.8898746350381, 56.3288905779201, 
72.3144340726956, NA, NA, 57.2196777244154, 57.4219542595438, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 50.1156476267096, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 74.7453159507017, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 64.7729450086223, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 51.9049325211991, NA, 55.6618610747051, 61.0650726803423, 
NA, NA, NA, 88.1366270204331, 57.3208722741433, 50.4122691292876, 
NA, 51.0243389949221, NA, NA, 69.3252625956917, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
79.0585774058577, NA, 80.9130534526268, 76.7148428538656, 53.6211370606275, 
55.2052785923754, 79.0428211586902, 87.6410390973498, NA, NA, 
NA, 80.3555555555556, NA, NA), MoorePct = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 55.7001513923509, 
61.7342432757929, NA, NA, 62.384575367408, 58.4948561204711, 
54.6173746766151, 58.5527662885458, 61.170828510005, 55.3869499241275, 
70.4410329221759, 64.1629563668744, 78.7496442462764, NA, 71.237957858946, 
72.2414316044889, 52.45303419381, 59.9000752857436, 81.8034633253555, 
NA, 72.6925845932325, 67.2737906257833, 60.2149634730036, 63.7242385555353, 
67.7532876458604, NA, 75.6634952428643, 75.7071547420965, 57.2199265381084, 
63.2393192907295, NA, 50.4126213592233, NA, NA, 79.7152502568619, 
79.2537987061832, 49.9390243902439, NA, NA, NA, 69.8607427055703, 
NA, 82.7147401908802, 70.964304741609, NA, 68.7882262996942, 
64.2539191019934, 60.9135004042037, 65.3114886731392, NA, 74.5462310484732, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 63.0405586892291, 77.8932968536252, 71.5352697095436, 
NA, 56.3877982482634, 79.799287795403)), row.names = c(NA, -67L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I have spent hours trying to figure this out and just can't seem to make it work right. The final map should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you also add the output from `dput(etable)`? Also, just an idea, but it's probably safest to avoid giving a dataset the same name as a function. Maybe something like this would work instead? `alabama_counties <- map_data("county", region = "alabama")`

Comment: I have added that dput

Comment: scale_fill_gradientn() which takes a vector of reference colours as its argument, and constructs a scale that linearly interpolates between the specified values.

Comment: oh lol never mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going in a bit of a different direction and got it to work. Here is the corrected code:

```
library(maps)
library(RColorBrewer)

# Define the breaks
breaks <- c(50, 55, 60, 70, 80, 90)

# Define the colors
colors <- brewer.pal(10, "RdBu")
jones_colors <- colors[6:10]
moore_colors <- colors[5:1]

# Assign colors
jones_cuts <- cut(etable$JonesPct, breaks)
moore_cuts <- cut(etable$MoorePct, breaks)
jones <- jones_colors[jones_cuts]
moore <- moore_colors[moore_cuts]
map_colors = ifelse(is.na(etable$JonesPct), moore, jones)

vote_data <- cbind(etable, map_colors)
vote_data <- vote_data[order(vote_data$County), ]
head(vote_data)


alabama_counties <- map("county", "Alabama", fill = TRUE, col = vote_data$map_colors)
map.cities(us.cities, country = "AL", minpop = 70000, maxpop = 300000)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure if this is the result of only having a subset of the spatial data, but this is what I got when I ran just this part of the ggplot code:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = vote_data, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = County, fill = cut(VotePct, breaks = breaks)), color = "black")  +
  theme_void()
```

[image: Weird map]

So that makes me think there's something wrong with the scale argument. If you want to keep using your original method, the color scale is probably where you can focus on.

I don't really know how geom_polygon() works and can't really tell if the weird lines is just the result of missing the full data or not, so I used a different method. Here's how you could make a similar map using a shape file, the `sf` package and `geom_sf()`.

```
# load libraries
library(RColorBrewer)
library(maps)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```

This shape file came from Alabama's open GIS portal: https://data-algeohub.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/al-counties/explore?location=32.629337%2C-85.433198%2C6.30

```
# load shape files
shape_file_url <- "https://services7.arcgis.com/jF2q3LPxL7PETdYk/arcgis/rest/services/AL_Counties/FeatureServer/0/query?outFields=*&where=1%3D1&f=geojson"

alabama_counties2 <- st_read(shape_file_url)
```

I defined the colors and breaks slightly differently because I decided to draw the map slightly differently. I only plotted one variable (the percent of the vote that Jones got). Then if the percent is below 50 the color is red, and if it's above 50 it's blue.

```
# Define the breaks and colors
breaks <- c(0,12.5,25,37.5,50,62.5,75,87.5,100)
red_colors <- brewer.pal(3, "Reds") %>% rev()
blue_colors <- brewer.pal(4, "Blues") 

overall_colors <- c( red_colors, blue_colors)
```

This assumes that there's no significant 3rd party and that the percent that Jones got + the percent Moore got = 100 for all counties

```
etable$jones_pct2 <-ifelse(!is.na(etable$JonesPct),
                           etable$JonesPct,
                           100 - etable$MoorePct)
```

This joins the vote data onto the sf dataframe

```
alabama_counties2 <- alabama_counties2 %>%
  left_join(etable, by = c("NAME"="County"))
```

```
# Create the plot with separate color scales for "Jones" and "Moore" winners
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = alabama_counties2, 
               aes( fill = cut(jones_pct2, breaks = breaks)) , color = "black"
               ) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Vote Percentage", values = overall_colors) +
 
  theme_void()
```

Here's what it looks like, the colors can be modified by changing the breaks and color values.

[image: New map]

Comment: I'm not super happy about how I did the scales on this, so it might only be a partial answer :/ hope it still helps!